# What does "const char far* inStrSource" mean?

Tags: c++, operating-system

I'm following article about boot loader,
( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/boot-loader.aspx?msg=3745692#xx3745692xx )
and I found this part:

```
"const char far* inStrSource"
```

Whole thing:

```
typedef unsigned char   byte;
typedef unsigned short  word;
typedef unsigned long   dword;
typedef char            bool;

byte CString::Strlen( const char far* inStrSource )
{
        byte lenghtOfString = 0;

        while(*inStrSource++ != '\0')
        {
            ++lenghtOfString;
        }
        return lenghtOfString;
}
```

Can anyone explain me please, why does he define char type as bool, and what is going on with this pointer thing?

MVC++ 10 recognize those as an error ( typedef char bool, and char far* intSource), however compiling with 16bit VC 1.52 works with no doubt.

Comment: The author is typdef'ing char as bool because he (or she) is a goofball.

Comment: @DwB: The code is from the second half of the 20th century, before `bool` existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [far pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer): a pointer which can be longer (ie: take more bits) than *normal* pointers.

It's used to refer memory cells which couldn't be addressed by normal pointers (ie: if pointers on your systems are made of 8 bits, you can only refer up to 2^8 memory cells; if you need to address more memory you could use a far pointer).

Comment: Thanks, what about "typedef char bool"?

Comment: It's an error, since in C++ `bool` is a built-in type. That typedef was often find in old C code, since `bool` wasn't a built-in type there.

Answer (score 4):

In a segmented architecture computer, a far pointer is a pointer which includes a segment selector, making it possible to point to addresses outside of the current segment.

You can find more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer). Actually, above definition is stolen from Wikipedia :)

EDIT: It seems that similar question is already answered in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774171/what-is-far-pascal).

Answer (score 0):

This code is made with Microsoft Visual Studio 1.52 , for 16 bit systems. That's the early days of C++, and implementations weren't really very standard conforming. There weren't even really any standard.

So, he defines bool to a char, since that C++ compiler doesn't have a built in bool type, and he wants one.

The `far` denotes a [far pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer) , which is a pointer made up of a segment selector and an offset so you could point to stuff outside your normal 64k of memory that "normal" pointers could address. You'll hardly see anything like that nowadays, as a flat address space if commonly used, and the parts(in an OS or bootloader) that still needs to care about the segmented memory model of X86 processors are often written in assembly