# Use of FAR* in C++11

Tags: c, c++11

Firstly, I have read:

A. [What does "const char far* inStrSource" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782673/what-does-const-char-far-instrsource-mean)

> From which I know that `FAR` pointer in a segmented architecture computer, is a pointer which includes a segment selector, making it possible to point to addresses outside of the current segment.

B. [what is FAR PASCAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774171/what-is-far-pascal)

> From this one I know: 'FAR is a fall back to 16-bit days when heap memory was was segmented. NEAR data was limited in size and faster, FAR was allowed to be larger but more expensive.'

I have been given an old C/C++ code to translate to C++11 which uses `short FAR*` heavily. The `short FAR*` type will not resolve in VS2013 (using C++11), so my question is should I be replacing the `short FAR*` data type [*I know the answer is probably 'definitely'*], if so what with? If not, how can I get this to resolve?

Comment: How about a `#define FAR /*nothing*/` and letting the compiler handle this stuff ?

Comment: I have referenced that exact question in my own question and SAID THAT IT DOES NOT HELP ME!?

Comment: @Quentin I am tempted by this as there are so many references. However, this does not sit well with me and I would like to make the code 'clean' by removing these likely redundant types...

Comment: The accepted answer from the second link pretty much does answer this.  You do what @Quentin said, or you just global search/replace them with nothing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja no 'they generally expand to nothing' is the best that answer offers and does _not_ answer my question above... I am happy to accept an answer from you which states 'replace `short FAR*` with `short*`'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should delete it since you're no longer working on a segmented memory architecture, I assume. On any modern system, the concept expressed as `short FAR *` is now expressed as `short *`, i.e. just a plain "pointer to `short`" type.

Don't mess around with the preprocessor, that just adds confusion.

Simply use any capable text editing system (your IDE or text editor are good first-hand choices) to delete the text.

Remember to search for the string `FAR` using all-upper case, with a case-sensitive search, and enabling any "whole word match only" flag to lessen the risk of false matches. Do a replace for an empty string, effectively editing out the `FAR` words from the code.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is a very clear and concise answer. You time is most appreciated. With regard to your edit above, I some time use bold to highlight the question not to indicate SHOUTING, which to me would be ALL CAPS. This may not be best practice anyway as it might lead people to skim over the question. Again, thanks for your help and time here...

Answer (score 5):

Just get rid of them altogether and let the compiler deal with it.

If you wish to erase them all from your code, with a context-aware IDE (any decent IDE should do that) you can :

1. `#define FAR /*nothing*/`;
2. Replace identifier FAR with an empty identifier;
3. Delete the remaining `#define`.

Comment: So are you saying my `short FAR*` become `short*` when using option 2 that you have suggested?

Comment: @Killercam (Edited) it's a to-do list, not a three-way choice. You just register an identifier so the IDE can locate all its occurences, then replace them all at once. So all `short FAR *thing` will indeed become `short *thing`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that (I shouldn't have referred to it as an 'option'!). But with the to do list, when 'replacing the `FAR` with an empty identifier' is this converting `short FAR*` to `short*`?

Comment: Yes, you want to completely remove all occurrences of `FAR` from the code.

Comment: @Killercam Yep. (Sorry for the interleaved edits, I'll roll my fingers 7 times before posting!)

Comment: There are still 8-bit and 16-bit microcontrollers that have a 16-bit address bus, but need to address more memory than 65kb. All of those use some flavour of `far`, so the non-standard keyword cannot just be dismissed like that. One may argue and say that 8-bit and 16-bit microcontrollers are to be regarded as obsolete, but they are still widely used in new designs.

Comment: @Lundin absolutely, but OP explicitly stated that these qualifiers were obsolete in his case, and he would just get rid of them ([See comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549639/use-of-far-in-c11/24549854?noredirect=1#comment-38020177))