# How to map struct wtih array[1+1] and method with FAR PASCAL from C to Java using JNA?

Tags: java, c, jna

I need to create Java interface to invoke methods from DLL. 
I'm not sure if the java code below is correct.

I'm already using JNA 5.4 and Java 11.

Struct in C:

```
typedef struct
{
    char CarId[8 + 1];
    char CarCode[5 + 1];
    char PrimaCarStatus[24 + 1];
}Cars;
```

Method in C:

```
extern "C" __int32 _stdcall FAR PASCAL  DG18_Search(Cars *CarsData);
```

Should it looks like this?

Java class

```
public class Cars extends Struct {
    public byte carId[] = new byte[8];
    public byte carCode[] = new byte[5];
    public byte primaCarStatus[] = new byte[24];
}
```

Java method

```
public int DG18_Search(Pointer pointer);
```

What's exactly array[1+1] and FAR PASCAL means in C?

Comment: About FAR and PASCAL, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774171/what-is-far-pascal

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, *JustCoding*.

The +1 you see is just simple addition, so you need to add one to the values of your byte arrays to map correctly.  I suspect the +1 is intended to show that there is room for a certain number of 1-byte characters, plus one space for a null terminator if required.

Your Java syntax for the mapping is wrong, though, you need to declare the array type, so the correct mapping is:

```
public class Cars extends Structure {
    public byte[] carId = new byte[9];
    public byte[] carCode = new byte[6];
    public byte[] primaCarStatus = new byte[25];
}
```

(Or you can preserve the `8 + 1` style numbers if you like.) Note the JNA class to extend is `Structure` not `Struct`.

As for the function/method mapping, you can read Fifi's link about FAR PASCAL, but unless you're building for really ancient operating systems you can safely ignore them.  While a `Pointer` would work for the mapping, it would allow you to pass any Pointer or Structure to the method.  It is better to use type safety and put the `Cars` variable in that function call:  JNA will automatically use the structure's pointer (`Cars.ByReference`) in the method argument, and auto-read the results into your local variable, so:

```
public int DG18_Search(Cars cars);
```